# Environment in Miktex for my proofs

Tags: packages, proof-package

I would like to create an environement for my proofs so that it looks like this :[image]

My proofs must be inside two vertical bars. I use this package :`\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What did you try so far? What is the result of you using the `tcolorbox` package and what does not work? Maybe you can provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you got and where you encountered problems. It would be easier to help you then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are not provided any `MWE`, I'm using the standard `article` class file, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %

\newtcolorbox{proofbox}{
breakable,leftrule=2pt,rightrule=2pt,sharp
corners,toprule=0pt,bottomrule=0pt,colback=white,colframe=cyan}

% ---------------------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}


\begin{proofbox}
\begin{proof}[D\'{e}monstration]
\lipsum[1]
\end{proof}
\end{proofbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]